# Iterative single variable solutions in large linear systems

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, krylov-method

I have a system where $A$ is a large $n\times n$ marix with fast MVMs. It may have many nonzero entries (albeit in a structured way so as to allow fast MVMs), and is not necessarily diagonally dominant.

However, $A$ is weakly positive definite.

$Y$ is a $n\times m$ dense matrix.

I understand iterative Krylov-subspace-based methods exist for finding $X=A^{-1}Y$, and they perform well. Are there any optimizations that can be implemented if I am only interested in finding:
$$
\textbf{x}=\text{diag }Y^\top A^{-1}Y
$$
In other words, I only want to solve for the $i$-th entry of the solution $Y^\top\textbf{x}_i$ where $A\textbf{x}_i=\textbf{y}_i$ for $Y=[\textbf{y}_i]_i$.

MVM stands for matrix-vector multiplication. In my application this takes only ~$n$ runtime compared to $n^2$ when dense.

Comment: You might want to spell out what "MVM" means.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth done

Comment: I believe the general case is still a research question at this point. I can think of several applications in statistics, ML, and physics that will immediately benefit from an efficient solution.

Comment: Do you know anything specific about the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$? If they are clustered, then we may use Krylov methods to construct a polynomial approximation $B = p(A)$ minimizing $\|BA - I \|_2$ that may be used as a cheap surrogate for the matrix inverse. Otherwise, Krylov methods may not be of much use....

Comment: @RichardZhang That's a shame; you're probably right regarding it being an open question (but I suppose that's an answer to my question - would you consider posting it?) In my case there is no guarantee about clustering of eigenvalues.

Comment: @RichardZhang If you run $k$ steps of a Krylov method, at this point you are only $O(nk)$ flops away from computing the full (approximated) solution and it would be just a minor saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach by [Papandreou and Yuille](https://ttic.uchicago.edu/%7Egpapan/pubs/confr/PapandreouYuille_VariationalBayesCompressedSensing_ieee-c-iccvw11.pdf) for diagonal $A$ relates variance estimation to the expectation of a quadratic form. The logic follows more generally: since $A$ is PD so is its inverse. Then $Z\sim N(0, A^{-1})$ is well-formed, and $\textbf{x}=\mathbb{E}[(Y^\top Z)^2]$.

If we can sample $Z$ then an approximation is possible (and converges). The linked paper has success when we can find the square root of $A$: solving $AZ=A^{1/2}G$ for samples $G\sim N(0,I)$ offers a way of sampling $Z$ since $A^{-1/2}G\sim N(0,A^{-1})$.

When an operator $A^{1/2}$ is available, this provides an estimation opportunity for variance.

Edit (5 years later):

Given only fast MVMs for $A$ we can actually achieve this. Using [a matrix countour integral](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11267) we can approximate MVMs of $A^{-1/2}$ using essentially a single iterative solve of a linear systems in $A$ (it's actuall $O(1)$ concurrent solves, where this $O(1)$ depends on quadrature error from the integral, and here concurrent solves means that Krylov iterates are shifts of one another, so we don't require additional applications of the operator $A$). As a result, we can directly sample $Z=A^{-1/2}G$ via this iterative routine.

The question then becomes, how many such solves do we need for our particular variance terms of interest $\mathbb{E}[(Y^\top Z)^2]$? At the end of the day, this is essentially asking what's the efficiency of estimating the covariance matrix for some $W$ where $W\sim N(0,Y^\top A^{-1} Y)$, which admits [Wishart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) statistics.

Edit edit:

Thanks to @YaroslavBulatov we can add some meat to the last statement, which is that worst-case relative $\epsilon$ error in expectation in estimating $\mathrm{cov}\ W$ demands $O(\epsilon^{-2} r \log m)$ samples, where $r=\mathrm{tr}\ \Sigma/\lambda_{\max}(\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma = Y^\top A^{-1} Y$.

While $r$ is unknown, it may be practically feasible to estimate using Hutchinson's trick. Sampling new $Z$ and independent Rademacher vectors $\rho$, $\mathbb{E}[\rho^\top Y^\top Z Z^\top Y \rho]=\mathrm{tr}\ \Sigma$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ we can estimate with inverse power iteration. The composition $Y\rho$ is a single vector, so this second expectation is (conditionally on $\rho$) a chi-squared statistic with degrees of freedom equal to the number of samples $Z$ we use for this error estimation, which is sub-exponential and concentrates.

Comment: How do you plan to solve $AZ=A^{1/2}G$, when the entire procedure has to be cheaper than solving a linear system with $A$, otherwise there would be no point in using it?

Comment: Right, I'm saying this is an approach only when you have cheap access to $A^{1/2}$ (say, $A$ is a large Kronecker product). If so, then you're only solving **one** linear system, $AZ=A^{1/2}G$, where $Z,A^{1/2}G$ are vectors. This is definitely better than the multiple linear systems required for $A^{-1}Y$, where $Y$ is a matrix. That's why I didn't accept my answer. Of course, this is only cheaper if the number of samples of $G$ that you make is less than the width of $Y$.

Comment: Regarding the edit part, Vershynin has some dimension-free way to estimate sample complexity of covariance estimation. If "stable rank" is small, the problem is easy -- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395098/dimension-free-sample-complexity-for-estimating-gaussian-covariance

Comment: Relevant theorem from Vershynin probability book https://i.stack.imgur.com/coQrg.png , $m$ is number of samples

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov That's a good link, thank you. One can imagine by choice of $Y$ stable rank can be as large as $\min(m, n)$, which is somewhat disappointing since it feels like the fact that we care only of the diagonal and not the full covariance, we should have an easier time. Indeed, across $k$ samples each mean sum-of-squares estimate is $\chi_k^2$ which is sub-exponential. However, the maximum among each such sub-exponential isn't clearly bounded, because the samples aren't independent.

I still feel like there's wiggle room in the case $n > m$ beyond the high-dimensional result.

Comment: Estimating trace of the matrix product doesn't seem to be much easier than estimating the full matrix product https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-triangles-of-a-graph , so it would be intriguing if you found a diagonal-specific procedure that's much better than full-matrix one

Comment: To be clear, my "edit edit" above is just saying it's easier to estimate the error in your estimate than it is to perform the estimate itself, since the trace of a matrix converges to its expectation faster than the full diagonal. I don't have any concrete proposals for improving on the stable rank bound.